# Python Loop support

Tags: python, loops

Hi everyone I have this task: Write a python program that takes two numeric inputs x and y.

a) [5 pts] The program should take numeric inputs continuously.

b) [10 pts] The program should ensure the range of x and y is between 0 and 1. If either one of the input values is out of range, smaller than 0 or greater than 1, then the program should quit.

c) [10 pts] Implement XOR gate, where the program returns 1 if both x and y values are different; otherwise, it returns 0.

The program should work for floating-point values.

For example,

If x = .3 and y = .3, then xor output should be 0

If x = .6 and y = .3, then xor output should be 1

If x = .3 and y = .6, then xor output should be 1

If x = .6 and y = .6, then xor output should be 0

So far I have done this but I still keep getting errors

```
x=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))
while True:

  if(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
        def XOR (x, y):
            if x != y:
              return 1
            else:  return 0
  print(XOR(x,y))
continue 
  elif(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1): 
        break
```

I get this error

```
 File "<ipython-input-337-80599671f24c>", line 13
    elif(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: The code must be recursive meaning if the input of x and y fit the criteria of being between 0 and 1 the code should ask for another input and the code should quit if there is an input put that is outside of the 0 and 1 criteria

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your indentation is off the `continue` and `print` statements should be at the same indentation level as function definition above like:

```
x=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))
while True:
    if(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
        def XOR (x, y):
            if x != y:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        print(XOR(x,y))
        continue 
    elif(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1): 
        break
```

though the `XOR` function should be defined outside the loop and the `continue` statement is redundant

```
def XOR (x, y):
    if x != y:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


x=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))
while True:
    if(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
        print(XOR(x,y))
    elif(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1): 
        break
```

in order to have the user repeatedly prompted for input the input lines should be within the loop and the `elif` statement should be an else statement either the condition is met and the function is run and the user prompted for another input or the loop exits

```
def XOR (x, y):
    if x != y:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


while True:
    x=float(input("enter x: "))
    y=float(input("enter y : "))
    if(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
        print(XOR(x,y))
    else: 
        break
```

Comment: Since a boolean is an integer (True==1, False==0) the full body of the `XOR` function could be written as `return x != y`.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function outside of the loop and get the input in the loop.

```
def xor(x, y):
    return x != y

while True:
    x = float(input("enter x: "))
    y = float(input("enter y: "))
    if not (0 <= x <= 1 and 0 <= y <= 1):
        break
    print(xor(x, y))
```